# python - OpenCV false positives

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working with OpenCV in python and am getting an absurd amount of false positives when I turn my threshold down, but when I turn it up I no longer get the image I'm looking for or anything. I have to turn it down to 0.4 to get anything. Does anyone have any ideas? Below is the screenshot I took, the template image I'm looking for in the screenshot, and the result.

```
screen = (0, 0, 1920, 1080)
ImageGrab.grab(screen).save("screenshots/screenshot.jpg")
time.sleep(2)

# Read the main image
img_rgb = cv2.imread('screenshots/screenshot.jpg')

# Convert to grayscale
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Read the template
template = cv2.imread('monsters/knight.jpg', 0)

# Store width and height of template in w and h
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.4
loc = np.where(res >= threshold)

for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 255, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow('Detected', img_rgb)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: False positives]

[image: 'knight.jpg']

[image: 'screenshots/screenshot.jpg']

Comment: Also, as a note, my bluestacks resolution (The program this game is running in) is set to 1080p and the 'knight.jpg' file is matching the scale of the 1080p screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template is at a different scale from your search space.

[image: Comparison of template and search image]

Since `matchTemplate` is only checking that single scale, you won't get good detections. You need to either correct the scale or search at a variety of scales.

Here's some (quick) code that will search at a variety of scales:

```
overall_score = np.zeros_like(img_gray)
# search scales 1.0, 1.1, 1.2...
scales = np.arange(1.0, 2.0, 0.1)
for scale in scales:
    # resize the template to that scale
    t_w = int(w * scale)
    t_h = int(h * scale)
    scaled_template = cv2.resize(template, (t_w, t_h))
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, scaled_template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    # pad the results so that we can combine them across each scale
    res = cv2.copyMakeBorder(
        res, t_h // 2, (t_h - 1) // 2, t_w // 2, (t_w - 1) // 2, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT
    )
    # combine the results
    overall_score = np.maximum(res, overall_score)
# we can use a much higher threshold
threshold = 0.9
loc = np.where(overall_score >= threshold)

# since we padded the images, coordinates are centers rather than top-left
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(
        img_rgb,
        (pt[0] - w // 2, pt[1] - h // 2),
        (pt[0] + w // 2, pt[1] + h // 2),
        (0, 255, 255),
        2,
    )
cv2.imwrite("detections.png", img_rgb)
```

Using this code gives the expected result:

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you for the reply! I am going out and just wanted to let you know I received your reply and appreciate it greatly! I will try this out when I get back :) I didn't realize the scales were off!

Comment: I really appreciate this response, I had no idea my scaling was off. When I throw it into photoshop it scales it down for some reason and I had no clue it was doing that, but I got it working now, thanks to you! Have a wonderful day :D